# Checking parentheses using stack

Tags: java

I am working on checking parentheses in Java and running in some issues.

The task is to check parentheses using stacks. That what i wrote so far. The problem is that i need to test many-many strings and have to put all these strings in an array.I created a loop that test one string at a time. The problem is that I don't know how to reset/empty stack when the end of the loop is reached. I think it causes the problem and wrong answer. I also need to be able to ignore any letters between parentheses, but my piece of code does not seem to work. I will be glad to hear any suggestions on how to improve my code.

```
 public static void main (String []a)

 {       

      String [] array = new String [] {"(", ")", "()", "{)", "(()", "())"};

      Stack <Character> symbol = new Stack <Character>();   

      for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++)

      {             
           String example = array [i];

           for (int count=0; count < example.length(); count++)
           {  
                char ch = example.charAt(count);   

                if (ch =='('|| ch =='{'||ch =='[')
                {
                     symbol.push(example.charAt(count));
                }

                else if 
                     (!symbol.isEmpty()&& 
                      ((ch ==')'&& symbol.peek()=='(')||
                       (ch =='}'&& symbol.peek()=='{')||
                       (ch ==']'&& symbol.peek()=='[')))
                {
                     symbol.pop();
                }

                 else if
                  (!(example.contains("(")) || !(example.contains("{")) || !(example.contains("[")) || !(example.contains("]")) || !(example.contains(")"))|| !(example.contains("}")))
                {
                 count++;
                 }         

                else 
                {
                     symbol.push (ch);
                }          
           }

           if (symbol.isEmpty()) 
           {
                System.out.println("String is balanced");
           } 
           else 
           {
                System.out.println("String is not balanced");
           }       

      }  

 }
```

Comment: "but my piece of code does not seem to work" => Your part is to tell us _exactly_ what does not work. What is your input? What is your expected behavior? What is your actual outcome? Any error messages? If yes, what errors do you get? And so on ...

Comment: One stack for 3 types of brackets/parentheses?

Comment: What happened to `stack.clear();`?

Comment: `symbol.clear()` or just create a new stack foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your checking to see if brackets are balanced within an array of different strings then place your code for 'bracket balance check' into a method of its own then from within the loop you're using to iterate through the Array of different strings call your method to check each string upon each iteration, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
    boolean balanced = areBracketsValid(myArrayOfStrings[i]);
    System.out.println("Index #" + i + ":\t" + balanced + " -->\t" + myArrayOfStrings[i];
}
```

Code to check brackets using Stack:

```
public static boolean areBracketsValid(String inputString) {
    char[] brackets = new char[256];
    // Parentheses
    brackets['('] = '(';
    brackets[')'] = '(';
    // Square Brackets
    brackets['['] = '[';
    brackets[']'] = '[';
    // Curly Braces
    brackets['{'] = '{';
    brackets['}'] = '{';
    // Chevron Brackets
    brackets['<'] = '<';
    brackets['>'] = '<';

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (Character char1 : inputString.toCharArray()) {
        char char2 = brackets[char1];
        if (char2 == char1) {
            stack.push(char1);
        }
        else if (char2 > 0) {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || char2 != stack.pop()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Yes, you can add whatever single character bracket types you like, even letters.

This method will return false if brackets are illegally placed, for example: **[(])**